# Auto Reminder in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have built an application that allows users to buy plane tickets, now I want to be able to set reminders in my application as in a script that continuously runs in the background checking the database.

Reminders should be sent via SMS a day before travel, I have covered the SMS part already. My problem now is generating a script that runs in the background and sends a reminder 1 day early to all customers.  I have never implemented something like this before.

Comment: Try a [Queue](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues).

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not really helpful to me at all, could you please explain further? Also an example would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The documentation is quite complete - I would suggest reading it, trying to implement it, and if you have a specific problem, come back & ask about it. Also, you could try [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=laravel+queue+example).

Comment: Also i have read the documentation on queues and that is in fact not the solution to my question.

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow, and should be closed as such. Please refer to the documentation in the first instance, or search for examples on the web.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

- create a function to loop through your records and get the ones that are one day before take of. And set a cron job on that route
- Then send emails to all that users

If you run the cron at night you can queue the mail job so mails will be send at a later time (morning).

Comment: I also did some searching and came across this "cron job", i'll look into it thanks :)